# QT: SQL Database DELETE FROM chosen table

Tags: sql, database, qt

I have a problem with using DELETE FROM in Qt 5.5.1.
I would like to delete a specified record from a table specified by user (I get the name and id via Line Edit widget and put it into Qstring name and id). I tried to do it this way, but it doesn't work. Can it somehow be done like that?

```
QSqlQuery qry;
qry.prepare("DELETE FROM :name WHERE Id=:id");
qry.bindValue(":name", name);
qry.bindValue(":id", id);
qry.exec();
```

Comment: Is this the only SQL statement that doesn't work? Does this same SQL statement work from the command line?

Comment: Yes I think so. Even when i put a specific name of the table in this statement like ("DELETE FROM Passengers WHERE Id=:id") it will work

Comment: You can't parameterize the table name. For the database to be able to prepare the statement, it needs to know which table(s) and which columns it is dealing with. Values can be replaced, because they aren't needed until the statement actually executes. Solutions? I'm no qt user so I can only be general. Either build the statement yourself `qry.prepare("DELETE FROM " + name + " WHERE Id=:id");` (yuk) or code for each possible table: `if name = "Table1" then qry.prepare("DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Id=:id");... ` (also yuk). I don't know if there are any better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Qt is escaping your binded values. This is important, otherwhise, a user can simply inject his own SQL commands.

Try using this Query:

```
qry.prepare("DELETE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = :name AND id = :id")
```

A not-solution would be: (please don't use!!)

```
qry.prepare("DELETE FROM " + name + " WHERE Id=:id"); <-DANGEROUS (SQL injection)!
```